# AngularJS $routeProvider: Routing is not working

Tags: html, angularjs

For some reason, routeProvider is not working in my code when I'm clicking on the link. I can't seem to find the error.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      template: "Order Details"
    })
    .when("/first", {
      templateUrl: "first.html"
    })
    .when("/second", {
      templateUrl: "second.html"
    })
    .when("/third", {
      templateUrl: "third.html"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<a href="#/first">show details</a>
<a href="#/second">show details</a>
<a href="#/third">show details</a>
<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: Here's a working [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/UTcSQ8GfTLFmzNyb6o8n?p=preview).

Comment: You're missing `angular-route.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fix :
Change **href="#/first**" to **href="#!first"**
And add to your angular app configuration the following lines:

```
.config(function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}
```

Here is the working plunkr for the same : [Click Here](http://embed.plnkr.co/6eGEC2sc8SDuYF1mLTX6/)

Since we are defining templateUrl parameter to which we provide the path of template to load, it is creating a difference. If we would have used template parameter to which we provide direct html code to load, then your code will work perfectly.